# reshaping a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

This is probably a simple one but I've been trying all day with no luck

I have a table that looks like this:

```
event   user country    plan

start   fred    uk      free
start   fred    uk      free
start   john    fr      paid
stop    john    fr      paid
stop    fred    uk      free
scan    john    fr      paid
scan    fred    uk      free
scan    fred    uk      free
stop    john    fr      paid
start   john    fr      paid
```

Id like to convert it into this:

```
           event
user    start   stop  scan  country    plan
fred    2       1     2      uk         free
John    2       2     1      fr        paid
```

Can anyone help? I've tried pivot but it keeps on telling me: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Thanks

Comment: Try `pd.crosstab(df['user'], df['event']).join(df.groupby('user')[['country', 'plan']].first())`

Comment: wow that's amazing, thanks!. Now to read up on cross tab and join.